# How do you calculate second Loop complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

For this for loop in python:

```
for(int a = 1 ; a < N ; a*=2)
      for(int b =1 ; b <N ; b++)
```

I know the code completes in `O(n*log(n))`, but if the loop is:

```
For(int  a = 1 ; a <N ; a*=2)
    for(int b = 1 ; b < a ; b++)
```

Will it still complete in `O(n*log(n))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes (and no)**. Going strictly by the definition of Big O, we will see below that the second algorithm is `O(n*log(n))`, but has a better bound.

First, let's review the ideas of the first loop. If we call each loop iteration a unit of computation, we can say the total amount of computation is `sum(sum(1 from 0 to N) from 0 to log2(N))`, which is just `N log2(N)` (maybe off by one). This result shows that the first set of loops is `O(N log(N))`.

Now for the second set. Repeating the procedure above, we have `sum(sum(1 from 0 to *a*) from 0 to log2(N)) = (log2(2 N) log2(4 N)) <= k [log(N)]^2`, so the second algorithm is `O(log^2(N))` (known as *polylogarithmic*).

Note that `k N log(N)` (for some k) is still an upper bound for the second algorithm, so strictly speaking it is still `O(N log(N)`.

Here is an image of the expected growth of the runtime:

[image: growth plot]

Red is the first set of loops, green is the second set of loops, and blue is `2N log(N)`.